# Unable to open .msg file more than twice

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010

The situation is a bunch of users export their emails as msg files into a central server location and would then open those files later down the line for referencing.

The problem occurs in which when a user double clicks on \server01\emails\email.msg file and the file will open fine the first time, if the user closes the msg file and re-opens then the email will come up with an error along the lines of:

> Cannot open file `\\server01\emails\email.msg`, you may not have access to this file or the file may be open by another person. Please contact your administrator

As soon as I close Outlook, the file will then become accessible to the user to open once again.

Does anyone have any ideas as to the root cause?

Comment: Figured it out! Outlook was running a PDF Addin for outlook that was interfering. disabling this solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out! Outlook was running a PDF Addin for outlook that was interfering. disabling this solved the problem.